# Passing variables from Tab to DefaultTabController - Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a DefaultTabController with two pages nested in a scaffold. In my scaffold's App Bar is a save button and I want this button to return a value to a previous page, based on a variable that is calculated in one of the tabs. How do I get this value?

Here is my DefaultTabController

```
DefaultTabController(
    initialIndex: index,
    length: 2,
    child: Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: fumigruen_accent,
        leading: CloseButton(
          color: Colors.black,
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
        ),
        actions: buildEditingActions(),
      ),
      body: Column(children: [
        tabBar(),
        Expanded(
          child: TabBarView(children: [
            //1st Tab
            GewichtsrechnerEinfach(),
            //2nd Tab
            Column()
          ]),
        )
      ]),
    ));}
```

And here is the save-Button I want to use to pass a varaible to the previous screen

```
  List<Widget> buildEditingActions() => [
    ElevatedButton.icon(
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          backgroundColor: fumigruen_accent,
          elevation: 0,
          foregroundColor: Colors.black,
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pop(gewicht);
        },
        icon: Icon(Icons.save),
        label: Text("Speichern"))
  ];
```

The tabbar Code

```
  Widget tabBar() => TabBar(
          labelColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          indicatorColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          labelStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          tabs: [
            Tab(
              child: Row(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
                Icon(
                  Icons.assessment_outlined,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 5,
                ),
                Text("Einfach")
              ]),
            ),
            Tab(
              child: Row(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
                Icon(
                  Icons.addchart,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 5,
                ),
                Text("Fortgeschritten")
              ]),
            ),
          ]);
```

and an extract of the GewichtsrechnerEinfach():

```
    class _GewichtsrechnerEinfachState extends State<GewichtsrechnerEinfach> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  num koerperlaenge = 0;
  num brustumfang = 0;
  var _koerperlaengeControler = TextEditingController();
  var _brustumfangControler = TextEditingController();
  num gewicht = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              //{two textinput fields setting the variables koerperlaenge and brustumfang are here}
          
              Center(
                child: Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                  decoration: ThemeHelper().buttonBoxDecoration(context),
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                      style: ThemeHelper().buttonStyle(),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
                        child: Text(
                          "berechnen".toUpperCase(),
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                          setState(() {
                            gewicht = Gewichtskalkulator().einfach(
                                brustumfang.toDouble(),
                                koerperlaenge.toDouble());
                          });
                        }
                      }),
                ),
              ),
            
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

The variable "gewicht" is calculated and changed in the first tab "GewichtsrechnerEinfach". So how do I get the changed variable to this main screen so that I can use it while saving?

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Hallo, mein Freund, could you please tell me more detail, with screenshot and put the GewichtsrechnerEinfach() code and tabBar() code, bitte.

Comment: Done - i added the code and screenshot. many thanks in advance

Comment: Hallo wieder, I reviewed your code, as i found out a thing, because gewicht is in a seprated screens and you do not access to it in another pages you need to have it. am i right? if i'm right i have a great clue for you to do it without returning the value.

Comment: So I have a Page A. Here I can click on a button and I am forewarded to the Page with the default tab controller. From this controler I enter two different screens (gewicht einfach and gewicht komplex). here the values are calculated and have to be passed to page A (via the save button top right)

Comment: that is what i said: you are changing a value in a Page that you want to use it in another pages or screen

Comment: if i'm right, may i change something add make your code easier?

Comment: you are right and sure :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I found out by chatting in comments section, you are changing a value in a Page and you want to use it in another pages or screen, this is why you should use StateManagement something like [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider).
As you said you need to change the gewicht variable and use it where ever you want.

step 1) please add `provider: ^6.0.5` (or any version that is compatible) in your `pubspec.yaml` and call `flutter pub get`.

step 2) now you should create a provider class to make all the variables that you want to use everywhere, alive. please create a dart file named:

> gewichtsrechner_einfach_provider.dart

step 3) now you should put these codes in you provider class:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GewichtsrechnerEinfachProvider extends ChangeNotifier{
  
   num _gewicht = 0;
   
   num get gewicht => _gewicht;
   
   void setGewicht(num newGewicht){
     _gewicht = newGewicht;
     notifyListeners();
   }

}
```

as you see `_gewicht` is private and you can use it alive entire your project.

step 4) you should add the provider to `main.dart`:

```
MultiProvider(
      providers: [
// you are adding your provider
        ListenableProvider.value(value: GewichtsrechnerEinfachProvider()),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: ...........
      ),
    );
```

step 5) now you should use its setter and getter of `gewicht`:

as you see in `_GewichtsrechnerEinfachState` you are setting the value and should do this by using `Consumer`:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Consumer<GewichtsrechnerEinfachProvider>(//note this
          builder: (context, gewichtsrechnerEinfachProvider ,child) {
            return Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  //{two textinput fields setting the variables koerperlaenge and brustumfang are here}

                  Center(
                    child: Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                      decoration: ThemeHelper().buttonBoxDecoration(context),
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                          style: ThemeHelper().buttonStyle(),
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
                            child: Text(
                              "berechnen".toUpperCase(),
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          onPressed: () async {
                            if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                              // and note this
                              gewichtsrechnerEinfachProvider.setGewicht(
                                  Gewichtskalkulator().einfach(
                                      brustumfang.toDouble(),
                                      koerperlaenge.toDouble())
                              );
                            }
                          }),
                    ),
                  ),

                ],
              ),
            );
          }
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

step 6) now you should use its getter where ever you want:

```
List<Widget> buildEditingActions() => [
  Consumer<GewichtsrechnerEinfachProvider>(
    builder: (context, gewichtsrechnerEinfachProvider ,child) {
      return ElevatedButton.icon(
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            backgroundColor: fumigruen_accent,
            elevation: 0,
            foregroundColor: Colors.black,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            // Navigator.of(context).pop(gewicht);
            print('here is your result: 
      ${gewichtsrechnerEinfachProvider.gewicht}');
          },
          icon: Icon(Icons.save),
          label: Text("Speichern"));
    }
  )
];
```

note that you can use your provider where ever you want even with this code not just consumer:

```
    var gewichtsrechnerEinfachProvider = Provider.of<GewichtsrechnerEinfachProvider>(context,listen: false);
```

as you see by changing its value the provider notifies to where you are showing it.

Ich hoffe, ich konnte dir helfen ;)

happy coding my friend...

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thank you so much:) will also look deeper in provider  state management. Danke!!! ;)

Comment: Bitte Schön my friend, you can follow in linkedin and you can ask what ever you want, i would be happy to help you