# When to use Consumer & when to use context.watch to access the provider values?

Tags: flutter, provider, state-management, flutter-state

Recently I discovered that we can access the provider value using either

```
Consumer<Model>(build: (context, value, child){
    return Widget(child: value.valueName),
  },
 )
```

Or using

`context.watch<Model>().valueName`

What is the best practice?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use Provider.of<X> vs. Consumer<X> in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58774301/when-to-use-provider-ofx-vs-consumerx-in-flutter)

Comment: Note that context.watch<Model>() is another way to access data from a provider, which is equivalent to Provider.of<Model>(context)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are the same. it depends on your needs.

`context.watch<T>()` and `Consumer<T>` does the same thing. Most of the time `context.watch<T>()` is just more convenient. In some cases where context is not available Consumer is useful.

if you want to find an answer that explained how to use provider you can use my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75267678/passing-variables-from-tab-to-defaulttabcontroller-flutter/75275211#75275211).

happy coding...