# Error: Could not find the correct Provider<Products> above this ProductsGrid Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building ProductsGrid(dirty):
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<Products> above this ProductsGrid Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
To fix, perform a hot-restart.

The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
other routes will not be able to access that provider.
You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

Make sure that ProductsGrid is under your MultiProvider/Provider<Products>.
This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

this is product-grid file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../providers/Products.dart';
import './product_item.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class ProductsGrid extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final productsDate = Provider.of<Products>(context);
    final products = productsDate.items;

    return GridView.builder(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      itemCount: products.length,
      itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => ProductItem(
        products[i].id,
        products[i].title,
        products[i].imageUrl,
      ),
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
        crossAxisSpacing: 10,
        mainAxisSpacing: 10,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is products-overview-screen file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../widgets/products_grid.dart';

// ignore: use_key_in_widget_constructors
class ProductOverviewScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My shop'),
      ),
      body: ProductsGrid(),
    );
  }
}
```

this is main file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import './screens/product_detail_screen.dart';
import './screens/porducts_overview_screen.dart';
import './providers/products.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (ctx) => Products(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'shoping App',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.lightBlue,
          accentColor: Colors.lime,
          fontFamily: 'Lato',
        ),
        home: ProductOverviewScreen(),
        routes: {
          ProductDetailScreen.routeName: (ctx) => ProductDetailScreen(),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I don't know where the problem is.

this is products file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'product.dart';

class Products with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Product> _items = [
    Product(
      id: 'p1',
      title: 'pastel color',
      description: 'A red shirt - it is pretty red!',
      price: 29.99,
      imageUrl: 'lib/assets/images/pastel.png',
      // 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/02/22/17/red-t-shirt-1710578_1280.jpg',
    ),
    Product(
      id: 'p2',
      title: 'prisma color',
      description: 'A nice pair of trousers.',
      price: 59.99,
      imageUrl: 'lib/assets/images/prisma.png',
      // 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e8/Trousers%2C_dress_%28AM_1960.022-8%29.jpg/512px-Trousers%2C_dress_%28AM_1960.022-8%29.jpg',
    ),
    Product(
      id: 'p3',
      title: 'fiber castle',
      description: '120',
      price: 19.99,
      imageUrl: 'lib/assets/images/faber-castel.png',
      // 'https://live.staticflickr.com/4043/4438260868_cc79b3369d_z.jpg',
    ),
    Product(
      id: 'p4',
      title: 'marker',
      description: 'Prepare any meal you want.',
      price: 49.99,
      imageUrl: 'lib/assets/images/markers.png',
      // imageUrl: Image(AssetImage('lib\\assets\\images\\markers.png')).toString(),
      // 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/14/Cast-Iron-Pan.jpg/1024px-Cast-Iron-Pan.jpg',
    ),
  ];

  List<Product> get items {
    return [...items];
  }

  Product findById(String id) {
    return _items.firstWhere((prod) => prod.id == id);
  }

  void addProduct() {
    // _items.add(value);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: did you try with `flutter clean` and rebuilding the app and if fails can you include package & flutter version you are using with others snippet part

Comment: yes i did it. and still same error message.

Comment: still failed to reproduce the error

Comment: can you initialise `productsDate` property in initState() ? With `listen:false` ofc.

Also There's no Consumer or Selector widget used.. My guess is the Products instance isn’t passed forward to the route

read here for more on  Usage of Consumer and extensions https://pub.dev/packages/provider

Answer (score 1):

you have to initialize your provider at first:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import './screens/product_detail_screen.dart';
import './screens/porducts_overview_screen.dart';
import './providers/products.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// attention to this line bellow
    return MultiProvider(providers:[
         ListenableProvider.value(value: Products()),

],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'shoping App',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.lightBlue,
          accentColor: Colors.lime,
          fontFamily: 'Lato',
        ),
        home: ProductOverviewScreen(),
        routes: {
          ProductDetailScreen.routeName: (ctx) => ProductDetailScreen(),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and pay attention to initialize your all providers in your `MultiProvider`.

for more information regarding Provider you can see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75267678/passing-variables-from-tab-to-defaulttabcontroller-flutter/75275211#75275211) too.

happy coding...

Comment: thank you , I did it but still same error message

Comment: please add your Products file too, and please flutter clean and run again with the code that i've put.

Comment: i did flutter clean and run it again , and again same error, I add the products file in post